# Creating dumb "passthrough" objects

Tags: swift, clean-architecture

Sometimes when using [Clean Architecture](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) it is necessary to create what I call a "dumb passthrough object" which just delegates incoming methods to another object as follows:

```
struct FetchItemInteractor: FetchItemInteractorInput {

    var output: FetchItemInteractorOutput!

    func getCount() -> Int {
        output.getCount()
    }

    func fetchItems() -> [Date] {
        output.fetchItems()
    }
}
```

...this maintains separation and consistency of the layered architecture. Unfortunately it's low value code which is time consuming and error prone to type and test.

Is there a way to use features of the Swift runtime or language to create these sort of object with a minimum of code?

Comment: Writing many of this, which just delegates, does not seem/sound/look reasonable. Why do you need it? When you want to hide detail of something, you would normally put functions in Interface and let the implementation implement that Interface. No need for intermediate Object. Why is that not enough?

Comment: If your interactor looks like this, something is wrong with your separation of concerns. Where is your business logic?

Comment: @plainionist are you saying that a controller or presenter should communicate directly with a gateway (ie other objects in the same layer) if the interactor would just forward calls?

Comment: No. I wonder where your business logic is. Either it is in adapter layer where it should not be or separation of your interactors is not optimal so that u have some having multiple responsibilities and some being almost empty.